# Entity Framework not showing up in Rider on Mac

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller

So I am just starting to learn Asp.Net and am using Rider on Mac as my IDE. I'm am trying to enable migrations, however, I don't see Entity Frameworks option in tools under project context menu. Below is the link to the image:

[image]

I was wondering if any of you have encountered this issue? If so, what did you do to fix it?

Comment: EF normally gets added to a project via Nuget. Have you remembered to add it?

Comment: Ya I’ve installed the latest EntityFramework through Nuget too but still no luck

Answer (score 1):

According to your screenshot, you've installed core EF NuGet. But your project is a classic one. Please, try installing the standard EntityFramework NuGet package.
[image]

Also, the following resources might be helpful

1. https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2018/04/06/entity-framework-support-rider-2018-1/
2. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-435#focus=streamItem-27-2810865.0-0
3. https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/08/09/running-entity-framework-core-commands-rider/