# Entity Framework not showing up in Rider 2019.2 on Windows 10

Tags: windows, jetbrains-ide, rider

My problem is exactly the same as those created not earlier, only I work.

Windows 10, JetBrains Rider 2019.2 latest version.

[JetBrains Rider Entity framework tools not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58017407/jetbrains-rider-entity-framework-tools-not-found)
[Entity Framework not showing up in Rider on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56391703/entity-framework-not-showing-up-in-rider-on-mac#)

I have already tried many options, I also looked for a solution in all possible sources, I can not see (Entity Framework) in the project folders.

This works fine in older versions of (JetBrains Rider) 2018, I checked there when installing (Entity Framework) there is immediately in the project folder.

Please be glad of any useful information, am I missing something?

Thanks !